# Make ODBC Linked Access Table Available to Users

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I have an SQL database with an MS Access front-end. The linked table I created is only available to me and no one else. I need the other users on the domain to be able to open this linked table. When they open the table, they get an error message that says the connection to the database failed.

What am I doing wrong to where other users (besides myself) can't open the linked MS Access linked table?

Comment: How do you have Access linking to the SQL database? Using an ODBC connection?

Comment: Yes I'm using an ODBC connection created via the ODBC Data Source Administrator > File DSN > Add...

Comment: In your file DSN what login credentials did you use? SQL authentication login or did you use your windows login?

Comment: I used the integrated windows login

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure how a file dsn works when using windows login. I'm not sure if it stores your windows credentials in the DSN and uses them when another users tries to connect or whether it tries to use their windows credentials. I've always used a SQL authentication login in when using a file DSN.

Comment: After the error message  about the connection failing, does it pop up a prompt for the username/password to use?

Comment: No it doesn't. Just an ODBC --connection to <name> failed with OK and Help

Comment: Yes, when you use SQL Authentication, it prompts your user for the username and password you have in SQL. You can choose to save that when you first create the linked table, however, it stores it in plain text in the access file, so it's not a secure method if you don't properly secure the objects in your SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to the SQL database using an ODBC connection, the end users need to have that ODBC connection set up on the machine they are connecting from as well.